# Facebook scraper using 302 redirect and accessing old site same domain name

Tags: facebook, share, http-status-code-302

Developed a site whose domain was pointing to an external host.
On finishing the development I pointed the nameservers back to where the domain is hosted.
Everything changed over smoothly, I did not have to use any redirects.

Sharing any page on Facebook however, gives me this:

[There is a 302 redirect. The Debugger is scraping the old URL for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVvKw.png)

Comment: How long ago did you change the DNS/nameserver settings? Facebook might still used cached data, if that wasn't too long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Changing DNS servers can take up to 48 hour to take in effect. If it was done recently try to wait a bit, otherwise you could contact the support of facebook,